# Syntax bug in SQLite project, can't find him

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I firstly try work with SQLite, I`ve syntax bug, but I can't find him for 5-6 hours

Code from MainActivity.java, in this class I call database:

```
package ua.bellkross.notepadjava;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
        editText.setText(userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME)));
    }

}
```

Code from DatabaseHelper.java, in this code I have syntax error, in methot onCreate:

```
package ua.bellkross.notepadjava;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userstore.db"; // название бд
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "table"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users (" + COLUMN_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT);");
        // добавление начальных данных
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE +"(" + COLUMN_NAME + ") VALUES ('Text');");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

It's message from logcat:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO table(name)
>   VALUES ('Text');
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
>                                                                               at
>   ua.bellkross.notepadjava.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:25)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>                                                                               at
>   ua.bellkross.notepadjava.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:33)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6766)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440) 
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)  07-26
>   10:03:09.757 1375-1382/ua.bellkross.notepadjava W/art: Suspending all
>   threads took: 8.571ms

Comment: Do you have a table named "table"? I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Comment: Table is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. It has to be in backticks to use as-is, and anywhere else it might be used later (with other queries, for example), so it would be better to use a different name to avoid conflicts such as that error shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a table with named users

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users (" + COLUMN_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT);");
```

and inserting value in table named table

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE +"(" + COLUMN_NAME + ") VALUES ('Text');");
```

First change the name of table in constants

```
static final String TABLE = "users";
```

Now change your queries

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE +"(" + COLUMN_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT);");
```

Hopefully this solve your problem also check other string concatenation issues if any.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `table` as a table name for insert so please change name of your table name in insert statement

```
static final String TABLE = "users"
```

Answer (score 0):

"table" is the reserved keyword. Please change the table name to any not reserved SQL keyword.